# Flink change stream window size during run time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have one stream is consumed by FlinkKafkaConsumer which will be joined 
with another stream for defined window size such as 
Time.milliseconds(10000).

How can I change window size during runtime to Time.milliseconds(20000)?

```
Stream1.join(Stream2) 
     .where(new SingleValueSensorKeySelector()) 
     .equalTo(new GPSKeySelector()) 
     .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(10000))) 
     .apply(joinStreamFunc).addSink(kafkaProducer);
```

Answer (score 2):

The window size can't be changed at runtime.

There are a couple of things you could do, though neither is very attractive. You could implement your own windowing on top of some sort of ProcessFunction. Or you could duplicate the streams involved, have both kinds of windowing going on in parallel, and then dynamically control which window's results go to the sink.

Implementing your own windowing would be a non-trivial amount of work, and spending the resources on computing both sets of windows sounds expensive.

Comment: Thanks for reply.